# Variable inheritance from an interface?

Tags: c#

I'm having a bit of a brainfart on my basic inheritance knowledge:

```
public interface IDrawable
{
    public double x, y;
    object GetDrawable();
}

public class Beacon : IDrawable
{
    public Beacon(string id, double x, double y)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Why isn't Beacon's constructor able to find the doubles x and y defined in its parent?

Comment: write your code and try before asking a question.Your code doesn't even compile!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code does not compile because:

> Error 1   Interfaces cannot contain field

Interface is about operations (including properties), they cannot contain data. You can use properties here but they must be implemented in you class:

```
public interface IDrawable
{
    double x { get; set; }
    double y { get; set; }
    // ...
}

public class Beacon : IDrawable
{
    public double x { get; set; }
    public double y { get; set; }

    public Beacon(string id, double x, double y)
    {
        // ...
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

If your base class must contain this data, make it an abstract class:

```
public abstract class Drawable
{
    public double x { get; set; }
    public double y { get; set; }
    public abstract object GetDrawable();
}

public class Beacon : Drawable
{
    public Beacon(string id, double x, double y)
    {
        //this.id = id;
        this.x = x; 
        this.y = y;
    }

    public override object GetDrawable()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

So the final conclusion here is - read about interface vs abstract class differences and decide which way you should take.

Comment: Aha, duh.  I've clearly spent too long in the research and managerial sides of things, and am forgetting basic implementation details.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This should not compile. You have to declare x and y as properties in your interface and implement the getter and setter in your implementation.